# Is there a way to programmatically intercept push notifications?

Tags: ios, mobile

I have an app that sends push notifications when an item is available. I'd like to programmatically take an action when that happens. Is that possible? Can I install an app that listens for all push notifications?

Comment: No, you can't. It would be a privacy violation

Comment: @Paulw11even on your own phone?

Comment: Yes, even if you granted permission for an app to access your notifications there is a significant risk of apps abusing that access and users may not understand the implications of granting access